# How to generate a slack never expiring token?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I need to create a slack token that would last for a very long period but all i can find are the test tokens and i don't know how to they even last for i tried to search in their documentation but all i could find were the bot tokens and test tokens, your help is very much appreciated, I used facebook's API and they got a way to generate a never expiring token is that available in slack?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know all of the tokens you can generate (and also those you receive when a team installs your app via OAuth) do not have an expiry date.

They are **active for an indefinite amount of time**.

You should be able to use them however long you want.

Comment: I can confirm this. I am have been using "test tokens" and tokens from the auth process for multiple apps for month now and they have never expired.

Comment: is this even safe?! Example Microsoft Graph uses refresh toknes to re-generate them